# Apache cannot access external drive on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, directory, linuxmint

I have a Linux server and a Windows server with a external drive for my website files. The problem only exists in Linux Apache configuration, where I cannot access the files for the sites located on the external drive.

This is the structure of my external drive:
 `/media/mintmate/NewVolume/Site` with two folders, one with `Accept` and the other one is `Testing`, both have the same website folders like `website a` , `website b` with test prefix for Testing folder.

This is what I have done so far:
I have created a file "`sites.conf`" in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` with this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /media/mintmate/NewVolume/Site
</VirtualHost>
```

and enabled this with `sudo a2ensite sites.conf`

Then I have edited `apache2.conf` file with these settings:

```
<Directory /media/mintmate/NewVolume/Site>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

After saving these files I've restarted the service(`sudo service apache2 reload` and `sudo service apache2 restart`)

When I go to `localhost` on the server machine I get this message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server". I have also tried `http://localhost/Testing/test-a/`and `http://localhost/Testing/test-a/index.php`and yet the same error message.

This is the output of `ls -al /media/mintmate/NewVolume/Site`:

```
total 10 
drwxrwxrwx 1 mintmate mintmate 4096 Sep 25 18:57 . 
drwxrwxrwx 1 mintmate mintmate 4096 Sep 25 18:57 .. 
drwxrwxrwx 1 mintmate mintmate 0 Sep 21 15:35 Accept 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mintmate mintmate 912 Sep 24 19:20 index.html 
drwxrwxrwx 1 mintmate mintmate 0 Sep 21 15:35 Testing
```

I have tried all the steps here: [How do I change the root directory of an apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server) and [Error message “Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server) and still no success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "When I type in localhost"   Are you typing this in a browser running on the server itself?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, its indeed on the server it self.

Comment: Can you add output of "ls -al /media/mintmate/NewVolume/Site" to your question?

Comment: Is the Virtualhost you show, the only one enabled?

Comment: You should edit the question, not post additional information in the comments.

Comment: Please edit the output of `namei -l /media/mintmate/NewVolume/Site` into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change the Apache user and group to mintmate?
The error clearly species that user have no permission to access files or folders.
You have to give apache user perssion to access website files.

For your reference:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/forbidden-you-don-t-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server-additionally-a-403-forbidden-error-was-encountered

Comment: The permissions are 777. This is a bad idea in itself, but it should provide the access on the file system level.

Comment: This did work for me thank you, I had to change the permissions for user.

Answer (score 0):

`Allow from` is the configuration syntax of Apache 2.2. Apache 2.4 is basically capable of using the 2.2 syntax, but when you mix both syntaxes [the result is not necessarily what you expect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html).

Change

```
Allow from localhost
```

to

```
Require ip 127.0.0.1
```

On the other hand, you can just omit the line, `Require all granted` already allows access from everywhere, including localhost.

Comment: `Allow from` was already in there. I did not change that but I will defiantly try out your solution.

Comment: This also didn't work!

Comment: Then you will have to go through the rest of your Apache config files and look for more permission directives.

Comment: I've installed Apache again and yet no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

I've changed next item in `apache2.conf` :

```
<Directory /media/NewVolume/Site>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and this one in `000-default.conf` :

```
DocumentRoot /media/NewVolume/Site
```

After that I've changed the permissions of the folder for the user like @antony_sebastian suggested.

`sudo chown -R mintmate:www-data /media/NewVolume/Site/`
and
`sudo chmod -R 777 /media/NewVolume/Site/`